Summary Formula in the Report
CallTime is similar to the created date of the record, and I have grouped it by months. I have a picklist field (FCR) with values of YES or NO. I created a dashboard that displays the percentage of YES and NO responses on a monthly basis, as shown below.

I want to filter to show only YES responses in this dashboard. However, when I apply a filter for FCR = YES, I'm unable to get the total count. To address this, I created a checkbox formula field called FCR Only YES, but I’m still unable to display the percentage.
My goal is to calculate FCR Only YES (19972) / CallTime (January 2024 Total: 55844) and achieve this calculation in the summary formula in the report.

